# Running mocha tests result in "Unexpected reserved word" error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

STEP: `npm test`

ERROR: "Unexpected reserved word"

I had this working earlier today and am not aware of anything I changed that could have caused a regression.  When I run `npm test` I get "Unexpected reserved word" and it points to an ES6 import statement.  My understanding is `--compilers js:babel-register` should resolve that issue.

I have tried installing `babel-core` both globally and locally and using `babel-core/register` instead.  Same result.

Here is my `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "fresh",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "remotedev": "remotedev --hostname=localhost --port=8000",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register 'test/**/*.test.js'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch --watch-extensions jsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "ramda": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^2.3.8",
    "react-native-sortable-listview": "0.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.9.1",
    "reselect": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.5.3",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "redux-devtools-filter-actions": "^1.1.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.1.2",
    "remotedev-server": "0.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is are 2 tutorials indicating this should work.

https://onsen.io/blog/mocha-chaijs-unit-test-coverage-es6/

http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/

Again, I was successfully executing tests with this script earlier today.

Comment: I've run into this same issue.  Did you ever solve this, @ken4z?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

then create `.babelrc` file with

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried that, along with several other babel presets to no avail.